# jQuery Mobile Responsive listview Centering

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I need help centering a slightly modified responsive jQuery Mobile listview.

Currently everything works perfectly, i just need to center the list itself on the screen. This means the list should be center on the screen no matter the size.

Also on full size desktop browsers, the list is outside the collapsible container. You can see its not wrapped inside.

ex: http://olajideolaolorun.com/dev/test1/index.html

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2>Team</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>Technical SME, Sun City, Gurgaon, IN<br>+00-124-567-890 &nbsp; +00-12-34-451239 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>IT Analyst, Dayton, US<br>+1-123-456-7890 &nbsp; +1-123-456-7890 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>IT Analyst, Duluth, US<br>+1-123-456-5188 &nbsp; +1-123-456-1016 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>Technical SME, Sun City, Gurgaon, IN<br>+00-124-567-3365 &nbsp; +00-12-34-033006 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test</h2><p><small>Intern - MIS, Duluth, US<br>+1-123-456-7890 &nbsp; +1-123-456-7980 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>Sun City, Gurgaon, IN<br></small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test</h2><p><small>IT Analyst, Duluth, US<br>+1-123-456-7890 &nbsp; +1-123-456-7890 m</small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test </h2><p><small>Sun City, Gurgaon, IN<br></small></p></a></li>
                <li class="ui-li-has-thumb ui-last-child"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><img src="_assets/img/lumia_800.png" height="60"><h2>User, Test</h2><p><small>Sun City, Gurgaon, IN<br>+00-12-34-56789 &nbsp; +00-12345-678-901 m</small></p></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Modified CSS:

```
.my-page .ui-listview li .ui-btn p {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}
.my-page .ui-listview li .ui-btn .ui-li-aside {
    color: #eee;
}


@media ( min-width: 38em ) {
    .my-page .ui-content {
        padding: .5625em; /* 9px */
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview {
        max-width: 78em; /* 1000px */
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview li {
        float: left;
        width: 270px;
        /* width: 30.9333%; /* 33.3333% incl. 2 x 1.2% margin */
        height: 5em;
        /* height: 14.5em; */ /* 232p */
        margin: .5625em 1.2%;
    }
    .my-page .ui-listview li > .ui-btn {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* include padding and border in height so we can set it to 100% */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .my-page .ui-listview li.ui-li-has-thumb .ui-li-thumb {
        height: auto; /* To keep aspect ratio. */
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: none;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview li,
    .my-page .ui-listview li .ui-btn,
    .my-page .ui-listview .ui-li-thumb {
        -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
        border-radius: inherit;
    }
    /* Hide the icon */
    .my-page .ui-listview .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Make text wrap. */
    .my-page .ui-listview h2,
    .my-page .ui-listview p {
        white-space: normal;
        overflow: visible;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview h2 {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 1em 1.3em 4.5em;
        bottom: 50%;
    }
    .my-page .ui-listview p {
        font-size: .7em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 1.25em 2em 6.5em;
        min-height: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    /* .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb h2,
    .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb p {
        background: #111;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    } */
    .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb h2 {
        bottom: 35%;
    }
    .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb p {
        min-height: 35%;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview .ui-li-aside {
        padding: .125em .625em;
        width: auto;
        min-height: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        /* Custom styling. */
        background: #990099;
        background: rgba(153,0,153,.85);
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: inherit;
        border-top-right-radius: inherit;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
        border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview li {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #111;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #111;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #111;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview li > .ui-btn:hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #33ccff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #33ccff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #33ccff;
    }

    .my-page .ui-listview li,
    .my-page .ui-listview .ui-btn {
        -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
        transition: all 500ms ease;
    }
}
```

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the container you should give it a fixed width example 960px, and with media querys adjust to more small screens...